# "Joy of Clojure" 2 edition. Listing 11.9 about promises

Tags: clojure, macros, promise, mutation

I'm examining the [Listing 11.9](https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/master/src/clj/joy/promises.clj#L27) of the named book (p.269 of pdf).

Could anyone explain me how `tests` value is being set (line `[tests all-tests :as results]`)?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the context of the question for people without The Joy of Clojure (a book I do enjoy btw), the macro in question is:

```
(defmacro with-promises [[n tasks _ as] & body]
  (when as
    `(let [tasks# ~tasks
           n# (count tasks#)
           promises# (take n# (repeatedly promise))]
       (dotimes [i# n#]
         (dothreads!
           (fn []
             (deliver (nth promises# i#)
                      ((nth tasks# i#))))))
       (let [~n tasks#
             ~as promises#]
         ~@body))))
```

And is used thusly:

```
(defn run-tests [& all-tests]
  (with-promises
    [tests all-tests :as results]
    (into (TestRun. 0 0 0)
          (reduce #(merge-with + %1 %2) {}
                  (for [r results]
                    (if @r
                      {:run 1 :passed 1}
                      {:run 1 :failed 1}))))))
```

and the final call to run-tests is like:

```
(run-tests pass fail fail fail pass)
=> #user.TestRun{:run 5, :passed 2, :failed 3}
```

Ultimately, the latter part of the macro is doing a let assignment and running the body, so you end up with

```
(let [tests tasks#
      results promises#]
  (into (TestRun. 0 0 0)
    ;; rest of body
```

In the macro, ~n is unquoting the starting back-tick around the  `'(let` so you can just read it as `n` which is the first parameter to the macro (well, the first parameter of the vector that is the first parameter to the macro).

This all happens after the macro has setup the promises using the custom dothreads! function that uses a thread pool - non of which is important to understand the macro.

You can determine more about the macro by wrapping it in a `(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(with-promises ...` which generates something like (I've replaced the auto generated names with something simpler, v1, n1, p1 and i1):

```
(clojure.core/let
 [v1 all-tests
  n1 (clojure.core/count v1)
  p1 (clojure.core/take n1 (clojure.core/repeatedly clojure.core/promise))]
 (clojure.core/dotimes
  [i1 n1]
  (user/dothreads!
   (clojure.core/fn
    []
    (clojure.core/deliver
     (clojure.core/nth p1 i1)
     ((clojure.core/nth v1 i1))))))
 (clojure.core/let
  [tests v1
   results p1]
  (into
   (TestRun. 0 0 0)
   ;; ... rest of main body
```

which clearly shows the parameters passed in are used as variables in the final let bindings.

However, in this example usage (i.e. `run-tests` function), the `tests` variable isn't actually used in the body of the with-promises call, only `results` is, so you're right to question it, it simply isn't needed.

Looking at the macro definition, there may be further optimizations for this case, as the tasks# binding doesn't seem to give anything extra than wrapping `tasks`. At first I wondered if this was about immutability in the dothreads! call, or macro-niceness for providing a closure around the usage, rather than directly using the parameter to the macro.

I tried changing the macro to remove `tasks#` completely and directly use `~tasks`, which seems to still work, and as "tests" isn't a required binding variable in the body of run-tests, you can drop both the `n` parameter from the macro, and the `~n tasks#` part of the final let binding without issue.

Actually after reading it several times it finally dawned on me it's to make the whole vector read like a standard destructuring binding.

EDIT: some more explanation on "tests".

This is just a name, it could be "foo-tests", "foo-bar", because ultimately it's used to define something in a let binding.

Had the run-tests body been something like:

```
(defn run-tests [& all-tests]
  (with-promises
    [foo all-tests :as results]
    (println "foo was set to" foo)
    (into (TestRun. 0 0 0)
      ;; rest of body
```

you can see how foo (and results) are just used to ultimately define variables (eck - you know what i mean) that can be used in the body part of the call to the macro. The body being everything after the initial vector `[foo all-tests :as results]` but in the original code, `tests` is declared but unused.

Comment: Mark, cheers for this answer. Especially for `pprint`. Could you explain me how can destructuring `[[n tasks _ as] & body]` work (skipping the `n` if `n`<=`tests` is not provided in a call `(with-promises [tests all-tests :as results] ...`? also do i correctly understand `tests` is undefined? (sorry for being so nerdy, it is practically the only place in the book which remains obscure for me :D

Comment: yes, the macro is called with a vector as the first parameter, and inside the macro definition it breaks it up into the parts. note the call is `(with-promises [tests all-tests :as results] <other stuff> ...)` so the first parameter to with-promises is a vector with 4 elements. The definition of the macro breaks this up into four parts `tests` -> `n`, etc. The "tests" is defined, it's a name placeholder so it can be used in the final body. I'll add more to my answer to explain.

Comment: tests has no value, it's a name that is all. The macro-expansion happens before 'running' anything and after it's expanded, that "name" is used in the let binding to define a variable. If you look at the macro expansion in my answer you'll see that "tests" isn't called, macro expansion puts it inside the `(let [tests ...])` and hence it's valid

Comment: you mean `tests` is a name available inside the `(into (TestRun...` part?

Comment: My God, Mark, cheers. It was mind block :D Wish you a happy coding :)

Comment: happy to help. You were getting hung up on the word `test`, when in fact it's `tests` everywhere, but really it's just a symbol that will be used as a name. far simpler than it looks :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`tests` appears to be a function, so `:as` puts the result (output) of running `tests` on `all-tests`.</strike>

(edit:)
Upon careful inspection, the `with-promises` macro appears to be setting the `tests` to the count of tests.

From what I'm reading (don't know much about macros), the arguments appear to map `("tests" "all-tests" ":as" "results") -> ("n" "tasks" "_" "as")` but what I can't quite get is that would imply `when` requires a value for `results` ("as") when we're supposed to be creating it. Anyway, the value of `tests` is set in the final `let` of the macro.

This code is *far* too clever, in my humble opinion. Fogus is a master, but this is not his best work.

(If I'm wrong, [hopefully someone will be inspired](https://xkcd.com/386/).)

Comment: Well, it looks like `tests` is being destructured as `n` in `(defmacro with-promises [[n tasks _ as] & body]` (see my provided source code link), so it looks like you're wrong...

Comment: Sven, could you give me more hint here. I see that macro defines `n#` as local variable, i just don't get the point why `with-promises` is made to take `tests` parameter at all (it is inferred from `tasks`<=`all-tests` amount)? do i correctly understand that `tests` is not being set? point me to the part i'm missing, please :)

Comment: Using macro-local variables with the same names as the input parameters makes the code a nightmare. I strongly suspect he is trying to show why mutation is bad. :-)

Comment: Sven, thanks for your answer. I upvote you, but will probably wait for explanation that will trigger my old brain on about the full chain of vars setting in his code :D

Comment: Thanks, I think someone who really understands macros better could help -- that's why I added a couple of tags to your question. Good luck! Also, you might find the later sections of "Clojure for the Brave and True" helpful.

Comment: I was inspired to work it out and put an answer up. The `n` and `as` take on the values `tests` and `results` during macro expansion and are purely used for let bindings around the final invocation of the body. The whole thing is macro sugar to make the call to the macro read like other binding types in clojure. Sadly, your answer has all kinds of wrong in it :(

Comment: Cunningham's Law works! :-) Thanks for helping him. I've been noting that many Clojure questions don't get answers or votes on StackOverflow lately, so I thought I'd try it out. I knew only enough to give a vague answer, so I thought I'd start off a response.

Comment: tests isn't the count of the tests. There are 2 distinct `n` vars in the macro; 1.  a name when it's passed into the initial vector `[n tasks _ as]`, 2. `n#` which is an autogen variable for the count of the tests. `n#` becomes a variable like `n__auto_12345` and is completely different to the `n` in the intialization vector. `~n` is also `n` just an unquoted version, and hence how it is used in the final let binding surrounding the body. The point of using `(when as` is a guard against a bad vector being passed in. if there are less than 4 elements `as` is nil, so the macro does nothing.